# Cloudera ToolRunner

Tags: hive, cloudera, hue, toolrunner

I am using Hue for accessing Hive Service. I Created a Hive table using

```
create table tablename(colname type,.....) 
row format delimited fields terminated by ',';
```

I Uploaded the data with 300 000 record perfectly. But while executing a query like:

```
select count(*) from tablename;
```

it is creating MapReduce job and at this time I get the following warning, How to resolve this warning.

> WARN  : Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement
>   the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to
>   remedy this.

Complete Log:

```
INFO  : Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
INFO  : In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
INFO  :   set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
INFO  : In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
INFO  :   set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
INFO  : In order to set a constant number of reducers:
INFO  :   set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
WARN  : Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
INFO  : number of splits:1
INFO  : Submitting tokens for job: job_1442315442114_0017
INFO  : The url to track the job: http://dwiclmaster:8088/proxy/application_1442315442114_0017/
INFO  : Starting Job = job_1442315442114_0017, Tracking URL = http://dwiclmaster:8088/proxy/application_1442315442114_0017/
INFO  : Kill Command = /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.4-1.cdh5.4.4.p0.4/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1442315442114_0017
INFO  : Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
INFO  : 2015-09-15 18:29:06,910 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
INFO  : 2015-09-15 18:29:15,257 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1.65 sec
INFO  : 2015-09-15 18:29:21,513 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 3.19 sec
INFO  : MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 3 seconds 190 msec
INFO  : Ended Job = job_1442315442114_0017
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning coming up from MapReduce as jobs submitted by Hive do not implement the interface. This can be safely ignored.

More about [Tool Runner](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=hadoop%20the%20Tool%20interface%20and%20execute%20your%20application%20with%20ToolRunner).